# NullPointerException when trying to show aggregate result?

Tags: apex, soql

```
    public class CustomRollupSummary{


        public Integer getSalarySum(Id accId){
                Integer salsum = 0;

                //Standard functionality
       /*        AggregateResult[] sumResults = [SELECT SUM(Salary__c)salsum FROM Contact  where AccountId = :accId];
                if(sumResults[0].get('salsum') != null)
                        salsum =  Integer.valueOf(sumResults[0].get('salsum'));
                        System.debug('..'+salsum);
*/

              //  Custom functionality
                for(Contact con : [Select Id,Salary__c From Contact Where AccountId = :accId Limit 100]){
                        System.debug('..'+con.Salary__c);
                     salsum = salsum+ Integer.valueof(con.Salary__c);
                     System.debug('..'+salsum);
             }

                return salsum;
       }
}
```

**In this line:**  salsum = salsum+ Integer.valueof(con.Salary__c);
I am getting nullPointerException, I am trying to show aggregate salary from every contact to a particular account.

Comment: You need to check for null salary value for employee record. You can try this statement===, salsum = salsum + (con.Salary__c != null) ? Integer.valueof(con.Salary__c) : 0

Comment: Not working tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use aggregate result. You need to add Group By clause

```
 public Integer getSalarySum(Id accId){
    Integer salsum = 0;

    //Standard functionality
  AggregateResult[] sumResults = [SELECT SUM(Salary__c)salsum, AccountId 
                                      FROM Contact  where AccountId = :accId 
                                      GROUP By AccountId];
    if(sumResults.size()> 0 && sumResults[0].get('salsum') != null){
            salsum =  Integer.valueOf(sumResults[0].get('salsum'));
            System.debug('..'+salsum);
    }
    return salsum;
}
```

Without aggregate solution

```
 public Integer getSalarySum(Id accId){
    Integer salsum = 0;

    //Custom functionality
    for(Contact con : [Select Id,Salary__c From Contact Where AccountId = :accId Limit 100]){
        // add null check here
        if(con.Salary__c != null){
            System.debug('..'+con.Salary__c);
            salsum = salsum+ Integer.valueof(con.Salary__c);
            System.debug('..'+salsum);
        }
    }   

    return salsum;
}
```

Comment: Standard Functionality using AggregateResult is working fine already, I want to implement custom functionality using above...

Comment: @avidForce check my updates

Comment: Thanx @Ratan Now its working fine!

Comment: @avidForce you're welcome..